# Chrome extension to capture another extension page

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I have a Chrome extension that I constantly use for debugging HTTP services. I would like to take screenshots of what I see but usually it has more than I can see on my screen (there is a scrollbar on the right). On a normal website I would use something like [Screen Capture by Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) but all such extensions work with regular websites only. I assume it has something to do with security.

Is there a setting to enable these extensions work on pages I want? Or maybe there is an app that can save these pages as either an image or pdf?

Comment: Which OS are you using? There are lots of screenshot apps (for Windows at least) that can easily do what you're looking for.

Comment: I use multiple OSes, that's why I prefer a browser extension. I can take a simple screenshot, crop it and stuff with any OS without any additional software. The main thing is that I want to make screenshot of the whole webpage I have opened.